# How to set Android ImageView alpha like this?

Tags: android

I have three ImageViews, just like left photo in below photo。I want set there alpha to this.
[image]

But...
I set iv.setAlpha() or iv.setImageAlpha() will result like this...
[image]

What can i do?

Comment: Using the `setImageAlpha()` method, try also setting the `ImageView`s' backgrounds to solid white. That is, `iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the alpha value of these ImageViews. You can just put a View above these ImageViews and set it's background to color like this: #33ffffff

**EDIT：**
If you only want to change the three imageviews(exclude the whole background), you can use this on each imageview:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.parse("#33ffffff"));
```

Comment: If he has a black background then the background will have that opacity too. But if he applies the `mask` only to each `ImageView` that doesn't happen.

Comment: @luiscosta You're right, but use the image resource as imageview's background is usually not so suitable. For example, the resource's width and height isn't good for the imageview's size and the he has  scaleType attribute in xml file.

Comment: You're right, using it on `background` is not very good but it works if he doesn't have to scale the pictures. Also, see my EDIT for another approach.

Answer (score 1):

I see you don't want an `alpha` but you want a `mask`. A `white mask` to be precise.

Instead of putting an alpha in your `ImageView` use something like this instead:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_picture"
    android:src="#55FFFFFF" />
```

In this case I used the image I wanted as the `background` and I applied a `white mask` in the `src`.

**EDIT**

**Another approach** is applying the `alpha` you want to **each** of your `ImageView`s while having each one inside a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/your_picture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: or just `android:src="@drawable/your_picture"` `android:background="#fff"` and call `setImageAlpha` with alpha you want

Comment: @pskink I didn't test that approach. I can't tell if the `alpha` affects the `background` in some API or not, but if you say so.

Comment: @luiscosta it affects only `Drawable` shown in the `ImageView`, it doesn't touch the `background` in any way

Comment: @pskink You should give that answer to this question because it is the rightest in my opinion.

Comment: @luiscosta this is the original idea of "Mike M", see his comment on the OP question, i cannot steal his idea and sign it as "mine" ... ;-)

Comment: @luiscosta i just noticed you are from porto, portugal. do you by chance know any good local IT market search sites? either around porto or lisboa?

Comment: @pskink You can always check itjobs.pt but I don't know any site like that. Usually I never look for work, people contact me via LinkedIn.

Comment: @luiscosta thank you for your help, i'ii check itjobs.pt then